# Non-resolvable parent POM in Ubuntu

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, ubuntu

I am not able to run my maven based **spring-boot** project on **ubuntu 17.04** even though it's running in windows nicely. So far it is throwing the same error as in the picture even if I try from my Eclipse photon IDE or the Maven CLI.

[image]

I tried changing the java versions of the PC and pretty sure it might not be the issue now since its **java-8-oracle** after a lot of testing with different versions. **wget** is not working for the terminal for URL http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 even though it's working in the browser. Almost trying from 2 Days now so desperately looking for some tricks to get this to work. Thanks in advance

Comment: In the window I see an error which starts with "Could not transfer artifact ..." the rest of the message is interesting ..!?

Comment: @khmarbaise  here it is :) `The project com.example:myproject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (/home/asela/Projects/Spring/SpringBoot/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:myproject:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.3.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 11, column 13 -> [Help 2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all the trouble i went through finally figured out the issue and it was related to SSL since after working on with this answer [issue with ca-certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48824473/how-to-fix-invalidalgorithmparameterexception-the-trustanchors-parameter-must/48824820#48824820) after doing those steps got it to work

```
sudo apt purge openjdk-9-jdk openjdk-8-jdk java-common
```

(Just purging and reinstalling the jdk was not enough, I still had a java command after that. Only by purging java-common that also went away and then reinstallation worked.)

Afterwards, I reinstalled java again (I opted only for openjdk-8):

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```